# Que erro é esse?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando mudar o css da minha aplicação em asp.net mvc 5, mas ao tentar fazer isso me retornou esse erro ai. Alguém sabe o porque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente seu [WebGrease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/) e seu [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization) estão desatualizados. Você pode atualizar pelo painel do Visual Studio:

[image: Extensions and Updates]

Ou então via comando, pelo Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Update-Package WebGrease
```

Verifique também se não há arquivos `.js` no *Bundle* de estilos. Não pode misturar os tipos.